# Looking to DIY some LED crown moulding in my home, I feel like crown moulding is something I can make myself. Looking for cheap ideas

Tags: lighting, led, trim, foam, custom

I have a small livingroom that I'm looking to add some LED crown moulding to as a form of indirect lighting since there's no overhead light in this room. I've looked at some websites and found a few options for crown moulding that are pretty cheap, but just trying to do research into DIY options as well just to make sure I've covered all my bases. Has anyone created custom crown mouldings? Since it's not weight bearing, I was thinking of cutting foam somehow since I do have access to a hot wire cutter through my local Makerspace, but it's a straight wire and idk if it can be bent.

Are there other lightweight and cheap materials that I could use other than foam that can be cut into a custom profile? Or is that just about it for DIY options? I'm certainly not against purchasing premade moulding, but it's hard to tell how thing are going to look based on pictures online, and I know some places will send you samples of moulding, but for a price.

All suggestions are welcome! Thanks :)

Comment: You can actually walk into a store to look at the moldings in person instead of relying on a 2d picture on line. Sure, you may have to drive, you may even have to drive a long way, but that's the best way to do it.

Comment: There exist aluminum profiles for housing LED strips, including styles designed for cove lighting. They might be something you'd want to consider.

Answer (score 3):

I would not use foam or similar materials. Yes, that gives you maximum flexibility, but any lighting, including LEDs, produces some heat. Just not a good idea.

The good news is that there are plenty of stock crown molding profiles available that would work just fine. You can even combine multiple moldings for a fancier look.

In fact, with a quick search I am finding *too many* options to really give good examples. But basically wood (and some other solid materials) are available in a variety of sizes and shapes. With an inch or so of open space (more might be better, but very subjective and depends on the type of LED light strips you are using) you  can install a light strip such that the device itself will not be visible and the light will show from the top.

You can get really involved and use this as an excuse to buy a [big fancy powered miter saw](https://amzn.to/49GyiQi):

[image: Dewalt miter saw]

But for a room or two (of normal size), [a miter box and saw like this one from Amazon](https://amzn.to/3I5M82K) is all you need:

[image: miter box/saw]

You also need to figure out how to feed the power to the strips. My recommendation is to use a UL or ETL listed power pack to convert from high voltage (120V AC) to low voltage (< 50V). You can run low voltage wires much more flexibly than high voltage.

Comment: I will take excuse for 500$ Alex.